# Closed form of the elliptic integral $\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{1+\cos^2(x)}\,dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, elliptic-functions, elliptic-integrals

I want to prove the closed form shown in Wikipedia for the arc length of one period of the sine function.

[Source of wikipedia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AuGl.png)

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{1+\cos^2(x)} \ dx= \frac{3\sqrt{2}\,\pi^{\frac32}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2}+\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$$

Could someone offer some demonstration for this statement?

Comment: Did you try WA?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the length of a sine wave from $0$ to $2\pi$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45089/what-is-the-length-of-a-sine-wave-from-0-to-2-pi)

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician  Not really a duplicate because no one in that post mentioned the evaluation of the integral in terms of gamma function, which OP wants.

Answer (score 4):

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{1+\cos^ 2 x} dx = 4 \int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx = 4\int_0^1 \frac{1+x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^4}} dx $$

Now use the [beta function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).