# How to solve these complicated SA and arc length integrals?

Tags: integration, surface-integrals, arc-length

My partner and I are working on a project for our multivariable calculus class where we have to solve the integrals to find the arc length and surface area of our three piecewise functions. We've used Desmos and WolframAlpha to get an answer but we can't figure out what steps the calculators took to get the answers. We eventually caved in and bought WolframAlpha Pro in hopes that it would show us, but there's no "show step-by-step" button by the answer where there was for simpler problems. This is our last hope before asking our professor to skip this part of the project.

This is the original piecewise function and these are the integrals and their answers: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fzsn.png]

Please help us identify techniques to solve these, and to those who do, thank you very much!

Comment: Are you looking for numerical or exact solutions? The arc length of a sine/cosine function [requires](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45089/what-is-the-length-of-a-sine-wave-from-0-to-2-pi) elliptic integrals

Comment: In particular, the third group can be evaluated in terms of the [incomplete EI of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Incomplete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind). The others might not be so approachable because of the composition of trig with nonlinear functions.

Comment: What do you mean by SA ?

Comment: Since they are producing answers as decimal values, it is quite possible that they are integrating numerically - that is, calculating the height of the function in fine slices and summing estimates of the area of each slice.